# Sticky Post Headers & Question Table of Contents

Tags: script

*This userscript is part of [SOMU (SO-mod-userscripts)](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts)*

## [Post Headers & Question TOC](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/blob/master/PostHeadersQuestionToc.user.js)

- Sticky post headers to help when scrolling long posts / comment threads

  - User, revision history, post timeline links
  - Clicking on middle area of post header scrolls to start of post (replaces URL hash)

[image: screenshot]

- Dynamic anchors for header-level text in posts

  - Clicking on header levels 1, 2, 3 will scroll to and replace hash in address bar, which can be copied/used to bookmark an important section in long Q&A pages
- Sticky Question Table of Contents of Answers in sidebar below Featured Posts module

  - Answer score, accepted, user display name, indicates mods and deleted users, datetime
  - Sorted by current answer sort order (active/oldest/votes)
  - Clicking on answer links scrolls to start of post (replaces URL hash)
  - Toggle deleted answers in ToC

    [image: screenshot]
- Sticky Candidate table of contents on election page

  [image: screenshot]

### License

[MIT](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/blob/master/LICENCE)

### Download

**[View source](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/blob/master/PostHeadersQuestionToc.user.js) ([Install](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/raw/master/PostHeadersQuestionToc.user.js))**

Userscripts require [Tampermonkey](http://tampermonkey.net) to be installed on your browser.

If you are on Android, your browser options are [Firefox](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.mozilla.firefox) *(recommended)* or [Dolphin](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=mobi.mgeek.TunnyBrowser).

### Code

This userscript is part of [SOMU (SO-mod-userscripts)](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts)

[Bug reports](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/issues), Forks, and PRs welcome!